# I'm an idiot by entering an incorrect permanent rewrite rule, what do I do?

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

Working overly tired caused me to use the wrong web.config file in my application, therefore applying a permanent redirect on the wrong URL!!

I was meant to convert:

```
http://www.mydomain.net to https://mydomain.net
```

but, I did this instead (notice .co.uk):

```
http://www.mydomain.net to https://mydomain.co.uk
```

Our .co.uk domain isn't used anymore but we still own it.

I managed to delete the rule pretty quickly from the config file, as luckily it's in development stages and nobody would have landed on it anyway, and I also deleted the rule from IIS too. However, my browser still gets redirected to the wrong domain but other browsers don't. So I assume everything is OK apart from my browser has cached the rule somehow and somewhere.

Have I done any permanent damage to how my site will run in the future and do I need to do anything else to remove this incorrect rule?

Comment: Clear the cache on your browser....

Comment: @ChrisS - what's off-topic about IIS Rewrite Module? And you commented on it! You're off-planet.

Comment: @MartinG - `Questions on Server Fault are expected to relate to servers, networking, or desktop infrastructure within the scope defined in the FAQ.` - although URL re-writing is really grey area. Anyway don't be too upset, you got the answer you were looking for, so alls well that ends well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `301` status means a "permanent" redirect, some browsers will cache it.

Clearing the browser's cache should do the trick.